# chaos-monkey v3.1.0 code compilation failed when compiling code with Java 11

Tags: spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am working on POC to do chaos experiment for target Spring Boot application. Purpose to make this POC is such a way one can do chaos experiment on any Spring Boot application without making changes single line of code change in target spring-boot application.

I referred https://codecentric.github.io/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/latest/#_using_external_dependency_jar_file for the same.

I tried to use https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.1.0 external library but my application is running on Java 11 whereas the external chaos-monkey lib is compiled with Java 17.

I checkout v3.1.0 source code tried to compiled with Java 11, but it failed. I need help to compile the code with Java 11.

Chaos-monkey v3.1.0 successfully compiled with Java 17, but for the java applications which are running using lower version (Java 8 or Java 11), it failed to compile and giving below error.

> mvn clean install using JDK 11

Output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project chaos-monkey-spring-boot: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/component/ChaosMonkeyRequestScope.java:[120,72] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/component/ChaosMonkeyRequestScope.java:[122,9] illegal start of expression
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/component/ChaosMonkeyRequestScope.java:[124,38] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/component/ChaosMonkeyRequestScope.java:[138,1] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[137,86] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[139,32] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[139,50] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[139,59] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[139,87] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[144,66] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[146,32] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[146,50] ';' expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[146,59] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Pratik/Documents/work/external_git_work_data/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/src/main/java/de/codecentric/spring/boot/chaos/monkey/configuration/AssaultException.java:[146,87] ';' expected
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: If it compiles under Java 17, but not under Java 11, then probably it uses language features introduced after Java 11. In other words, you will probably not be able to compile it. Have you checked if there is an **older** version that works with Java 11? For example, Spring Boot 3.0 and higher require Java 17 or higher, while Spring Boot 2.7 requires Java 8 or higher. According to the [releases list](https://github.com/codecentric/chaos-monkey-spring-boot/releases), chaos-monkey-spring-boot 2.7.2 is for Spring Boot 2.7.x, so maybe you should use that instead.

Comment: That same releases list also shows that since chaos-monkey-spring-boot 3.0.0, it requires Java 17.